# Date range in select

Tags: sql, firebird

I have this table

```
CREATE TABLE Table1 (
    MY_ID  INTEGER NOT NULL,
    SCAN_TIME    TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    WORKCELL_ID  SMALLINT
);
```

My problem when I use select SQL to get records between two dates I get empty result if the user select the same date for the two dates

For ex:

```
Select * from Table1 
where SCAN_TIME between '20.9.2014' and '20.9.2014'
```

Although there are records in that date '20.9.2014' but I get empty result and I get results only if I increase the second date by one day to be '21.9.2014' !! why is that and how I should fix ?

Comment: You're missing the word `BETWEEN`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you used `timestamp` as the type, and things messed up due to the time portion. Try to use `Date`.

When you said between 2014-09-20 and 2014-09-20, you are actually saying between 2014-09-20 midnight and 2014-09-20 midnight, apparently nothing falls in between other than the exact moment of midnight.

If you cannot control the table structure, do what [PM 77-1](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2055998/pm-77-1) suggested in his comment below - use cast to cast `timestamp` into `date`:

```
select 1 from table1
where cast(scan_time as date) between 'someday1' and 'someday2';
```

Comment: ... or CAST to DATE in the query

Answer (score 5):

A `TIMESTAMP` contains both a date and a time. Since you're not specifying the time in your `WHERE` clause, it's using the beginning of the day for both times. So you're actually writing the equivalent of:

```
WHERE SCAN_TIME between '20.9.2014 00:00:00' and '20.9.2014 00:00:00'
```

Unless the time part of the timestamp is actually `00:00:00`, it won't satisfy this criterion. You should convert the timestamp to a date, or specify the times in your range, e.g.

```
WHERE SCAN_TIME between '20.9.2014 00:00:00' and '20.9.2014 23:59:59'
```